# Is there an example of ʔɓ/ʔɗ sounds in contrast to ʔb/ʔd in Vietnamese?

Tags: phonology, vietnamese

I'm unable to distinguish between the preglottalized implosives ɓ/ɗ and the preglottalized explosives b/d in Vietnamese. Is there any audio sample of these sounds that would allow me to make out the difference? Wikipedia has audio for ɓ/ɗ, but not for ʔb/ʔd.

Answer (score 1):

[My trying pronouncing those sounds](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1r-vUsCW4hODJD0jpEh_-BqDzzddLp94M). Each sound is pronounced twice with the rime -oi (as written ‘boi’ and ‘đoi’).

First record: b ɓ ʔb ʔɓ

Second record: d ɗ ʔd ʔɗ

Personally, the pronunciation with ʔ phonetic trait is felt highly emphasizing being uttered.

I’m Vietnamese and major in linguistic. Hope this could help you a little bit.

Would you be specific on what theories or researches that have come up with the model of ʔb ʔɓ ʔd ʔɗ, which you mention here?